# More than two similar lines in a row fits me

Tags: python, file, if-statement, line

I've got the .txt file like this within:

```
....

Crista

7:3

2:0

Wiki

4:1

6:2

3:2

6:8

Pope

5:2

0:1


....
```

Code to find all lines with digits and append it to list:

```
pp=open('mine.txt')
ll=[]

for line in pp:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.findall('^\d{1}:\d{1}', line):
        digits=line
        ll.append(digits)
```

My output:

```
ll=['7:3', '2:0', '4:1', '6:2', '3:2', '6:8', '5:2', '0:1']
```

If there's more than two lines with digits in a row I don't need them in the list

So my desired output is:

```
ll=['7:3', '2:0', '4:1', '6:2', '5:2', '0:1']
```

How can I get it?

Comment: why not simply put a counter variable in your for loop, that resets if there is no number. In your if statement you can simply test if the the counter is smaller than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import re
pp=open('mine.txt')
ll=[]

count = 0
for line in pp:
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
    if re.findall('^\d{1}:\d{1}', line):
        if count < 2 :
            digits=line
            ll.append(digits)
        count += 1
    elif line != "" :
        count = 0
print ( ll )
```